# How can I prevent prettier from changing case of css selectors?

Tags: vue.js, sass, nativescript, prettier

I want to configure prettier in my nativescript vue project. I use tslint + prettier + tslint-config-prettier plugin, created some basic configuration, setup file watchers etc. The problem is, that prettier modifies the cases of my CSS selectors in *.vue files e.g Label => label, which destroys styling of the whole app.
How can I prevent it? Css is a part of *.vue file, therefore I can't simply ignore *.scss files.

Comment: This seems connected https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4110